# How to add domain url in image src using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to add a domain url to an image src without replacing the image name:

Domain Url : http://www.example.com

Before:

```
<img src="images/old.gif">
```

After:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/old.gif">
```

I have tried using javascript but no luck:

```
document.getElementById("footer").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "http://www.example.com";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#footer > img").attr("src", "http://site.com/" + $("#footer > img").attr("src") );
```

Or, you might try check out the [base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank" />
</head>

<body>
    <img src="stickman.gif" />
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
</body>
```

Comment: They want to change the src of the img in the footer, not the footer

Comment: its ok..edit here $("#footer img").attr("src", "http://site.com/" + $("#footer img").attr("src") );   thanks...